# ionic 2 blank screen error (sometime black/white) along with Application Error on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Getting this error:

1. Displayed splash.
2. Displayed black/White Screen.
3. Application Error!

[image]

"ionic info" output..

[image]

Comment: Can you put "ionic info" output?

Comment: Added "ionic info" output in question.

Comment: Maybe upgrading ionic framework  [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and also ionic app script [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks amin, but still White Screen problem not resolved [1) Displayed splash. 2) Displayed White Screen. 3) App opened.] Now, how to resolve White Screen problem!

Comment: Run app on chrome and see if you have any error in console?

Comment: No error in chrome console.

Comment: If your pages are not a lot, create another project and transfer your pages to the new project. Don't forget to run in every steep.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution:

adding these to config.xml

```js
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```